# Was Martin Packard of Varian Associates related to David Packard of Hewlett-Packard?

Tags: biographical-details, physicists

I came across an entry for the *Proceedings of the American Physical Society* which was published in *Phys. Rev.* volume 93 page 939 (1954) under the heading "Minutes of the Stanford Meeting December 28, 29 and 30, 1953". The entry is by Martin Packard and Russell Varian, both of Varian Associates, and was titled "Free Nuclear Induction in the Earth's Magnetic Field".  It's basically an early report of NMR in earth's magnetic field.

David Packard was one of the founders of Hewlett-Packard, and Russell Varian was the founder of Varian Associates, both important early Silicon Valley outfits

- [David Packard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Packard) (b. 1912) earned a Masters in electrical engineering from Stanford in 1938.
- [Martin Packard](https://oac.cdlib.org/findaid/ark:/13030/c808662x/) (b. 1921) was a graduate student at Stanford around 1945-1946.

Does anyone know if these two Packards were biologically related?  They are too close in age to be a father-son pair but perhaps they were cousins?  I'm curious because they both worked in electrical engineering at Stanford not too far apart in time, and both had significant success in their careers.

Comment: @njuffa I looked at a bunch of obits and related documents as well and all relatives were pretty generic... "survived by two children".  I may have to try to see if anyone has family trees on Ancestry.

Comment: Links, please. Ideally, DOI links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One source, with a negative answer:

- [The HP Phenomenon: Innovation And Business Transformation](https://doi.org/10.1515/9780804772617), by Charles House and Raymond Price, claims of Martin Packard, [**"no relation to Dave"** (p. 123)](https://books.google.com/books?id=OsTnDv6d2DwC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22The+HP+Phenomenon%22+%22martin+packard%22+%22dave%22&source=bl&ots=Ma3UZopnIq&sig=ACfU3U0ja5ErbmNm4tPz4Ax-Jka6cOCj4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRlbvRgJuAAxV8C0QIHSfDAyQQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22The%20HP%20Phenomenon%22%20%22martin%20packard%22%20%22dave%22&f=false).

Accord to [Varian Associates: An Early History](https://www.cpii.com/docs/files/Varian%20Associates%20-%20An%20Early%20History.pdf), David Packard was on the board of directors of Varian in 1954 (p. 15, photo p. 14). So Martin Packard and David Packard almost certainly knew each other.